# Unable to print ref cursor

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, sys-refcursor

I am not able to print a ref cursor opened from a procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RMAN_COMMON.backup_report(P_OUT OUT sys_refcursor)
is
--P_OUT SYS_REFCURSOR;
NAME varchar2(100) ;

cursor c1
is
select owner || '.' || VIEW_NAME as NAME 
from  dba_views  
where owner like 'RMAN_%' 
and owner  !='RMAN_COMMON' 
and VIEW_NAME ='RC_RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS';

BEGIN
    for rec1 in c1     
     Loop
fetch c1 into NAME;       
           OPEN P_OUT FOR 'SELECT db_name, start_time, end_time, input_type, status, time_taken_display, output_bytes_display, output_device_type FROM ' || NAME;

     close P_OUT;
     end loop;
end;
/
```

That compiles without errors but when I call it I can't print the OUT parameter value:

```
SQL> var rc2 refcursor;
SQL> execute backup_report(:rc2);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>  print rc2
ERROR:
ORA-24338: statement handle not executed


SP2-0625: Error printing variable "rc2"
```

Comment: CODE update , now it seems better

Answer (score 0):

The ORA-24338 error is because you are closing `p_out` inside the procedure; remove that line from your loop

The ref cursor still has to be open for the client to be able to work with it. And it remains open until the client session ends or it explicitly closes it.

It's also possible that your explicit cursor `c1` never finds any rows, in which case it will never be opened, which will also get the same error in SQL*Plus. Assuming at least one matching view does exist though, it doesn't really make sense to open the ref cursor multiple times (if there are multiple views, with different owners), so you might as well exit after the first fetch.

Fetching explicitly inside the loop is also not right; though if you were actually doing that you'd get `ORA-01001: invalid cursor`.

So you could do:

```
...
begin
    for rec1 in c1 loop
      open p_out for 'SELECT db_name, start_time, end_time, input_type, status, time_taken_display, output_bytes_display, output_device_type FROM '
        || rec1.NAME;
      exit; -- or return since you don't do anything after the loop
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Or avoid the loop and do a single fetch into a variable:

```
...
begin
    open c1;
    fetch c1 into NAME;
    open p_out for 'SELECT db_name, start_time, end_time, input_type, status, time_taken_display, output_bytes_display, output_device_type FROM '
      || NAME;
    close c1;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the incorrect PL/SQL procedure. 
The `for` is incompatible with the `fetch`, you can't use both. Moreover you can't close the cursor before returning it or it will be unusable.

Here's an example of correct procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE backup_report(P_OUT OUT sys_refcursor) IS
BEGIN

    FOR rec1 IN (
        SELECT owner || '.' || view_name AS name 
        FROM  dba_views  
        WHERE owner LIKE 'RMAN_%' 
        AND owner  !='RMAN_COMMON' 
        AND VIEW_NAME ='RC_RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS';
    ) LOOP
           OPEN P_OUT FOR 'SELECT * FROM ' || rec1.NAME;
           RETURN;
     END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite code according to your answers. It is better now, but I get output only from one table RMAN_B2ETEST.RC_RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS. Dynamic table name is the key, I thing there must be a loop.

CREATE OR REPLACE function  RMAN_COMMON.backup_report
return sys_refcursor  is

P_OUT SYS_REFCURSOR;

V_OWNER dba_views.owner%type;
V_VIEW_NAME dba_views.view_name%type;

cursor c1
is
select owner, VIEW_NAME as NAME from  dba_views  where owner like 'RMAN_%' and owner  !='RMAN_COMMON' and VIEW_NAME ='RC_RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS';

BEGIN
open c1;
fetch c1 into V_OWNER, V_VIEW_NAME;

OPEN P_OUT FOR 'SELECT db_name, start_time, end_time, input_type, status, time_taken_display, output_bytes_display, output_device_type FROM ' || V_OWNER || '.' || V_VIEW_NAME;
return P_OUT;

close c1;

end;
/

select backup_report() from dual;

.
.
.
.
B2ETEST  25-APR-16 25-APR-16 DB FULL       COMPLETED               00:13:08                          57.79G            SBT_TAPE
B2ETEST  15-MAY-16 15-MAY-16 DB FULL       COMPLETED               00:10:29                          58.41G            SBT_TAPE
B2ETEST  18-MAY-16 18-MAY-16 DB FULL       COMPLETED               00:35:14                          58.42G            SBT_TAPE
B2ETEST  02-JUN-16 02-JUN-16 DB FULL       COMPLETED               00:08:09                          58.94G            SBT_TAPE
B2ETEST  11-MAR-16 11-MAR-16 DB FULL       COMPLETED               00:10:36                          56.02G            SBT_TAPE
B2ETEST  27-MAR-16 27-MAR-16 DB FULL       COMPLETED               00:10:37                          56.36G            SBT_TAPE
B2ETEST  29-MAR-16 29-MAR-16 DB FULL       COMPLETED               00:10:41                          56.36G            SBT_TAPE
B2ETEST  31-MAR-16 31-MAR-16 DB FULL       COMPLETED               00:12:23                          56.95G            SBT_TAPE
B2ETEST  02-APR-16 02-APR-16 DB FULL       COMPLETED               00:12:53                          57.05G            SBT_TAPE
B2ETEST  24-APR-16 24-APR-16 DB FULL       COMPLETED               00:11:11                          57.78G            SBT_TAPE
B2ETEST  29-APR-16 29-APR-16 DB FULL       COMPLETED               00:11:40                          58.04G            SBT_TAPE

DB_NAME  START_TIM END_TIME  INPUT_TYPE    STATUS                  TIME_TAKEN_DISPLAY             OUTPUT_BYTES_DISPLAY OUTPUT_DEVICE_TYP

---

B2ETEST  04-MAY-16 04-MAY-16 DB FULL       COMPLETED               00:14:54                          58.06G            SBT_TAPE

78 rows selected.